# Update source activity before exit transition

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-transitions

[image]

I need help about transition between activities:

I have two activities A and B and both have a ViewPager with the same image list. Every page has an ImageView with the `transitionName` equals to ​​​​​​​​**image_x**​​​​ where​​​​​​​​ **x** is the page index.

A starts activity B calling `ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation` and the enter transition is totally fine.

The problem is the following: when I close activity B, the exit transition does not initialize the view pager of activity A at the same position of B.

When user closes B, the latter sets the current page position in the result. In `onActivityResult` of activity A, I call the `setCurrentItem` and the behavior is showed in the gif.

Is there a way to update activity A before the exit transition starts?

Comment: Activity result is the best way of doing this because you do not have the object of activity so activity result is the best way to implement it.

Comment: @PratikGoyal yes but acting this way the exit transition is as showed in the gif, and it is very bad. I would like to see the exit transition just like the start transition (from A to B).

Comment: What if you eliminate the transition animation in the viewPager when coming back to A (if possible)? If it changes instantly, the user wouldn't notice.

Comment: @Nilzor If I remove the exit transition and the animation of the viewpager when changing the page there are no problems. I wanted to know if there were a way to avoid this solution.

Comment: Yea I was suggesting to remove it only temporary, so that the ViewPager animations are there when the user interacts with it but not when the system goes back. But I guess the exit page transition will be a problem as well, as there will be some milliseconds the old image is shown

Comment: @fran: you can use `interface` between **A** and **B**. When you get page change event in **B**, pass event through `interface` to **A** Activity

Comment: @fran I have solved your query... please check my answer... i used `interface` concept for solution... i hope this will help you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do achieve that if you use `setCurrentItem` in the [**`onActivityReenter`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityReenter(int,%20android.content.Intent)) instead of in `onActivityResult` (in your `Activity`**`A`**).

Just be sure you:

1. Before finishing `Activity`**`B`**, set the result (either with [`setResult(int resultCode)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int)) or [`setResult(int resultCode, Intent data)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int,%20android.content.Intent)))
2. Call [`supportFinishAfterTransition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#supportFinishAfterTransition()) (or [`finishAfterTransition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAfterTransition())) instead of regular [`finish()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()) to "close" the `Activity`**`B`**.

---

To summerize:

in `Activity`**`B`**:

```
public void close(){
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra(KEY_CURRENT_ITEM, mFullscreenViewPager.getCurrentItem());
    setResult(RESULT_CODE, data);
    supportFinishAfterTransition();
}
```

in `Activity`**`A`**:

```
@Override
public void onActivityReenter(int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityReenter(resultCode, data);
    if (data.hasExtra(KEY_CURRENT_ITEM)){
         mViewPager.setCurrentItem(data.getIntExtra(KEY_CURRENT_ITEM, 0), false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer seems correct but the transition still shows a strange behavior: http://giphy.com/gifs/d3l2J0f2o84YL0tO

Comment: Although it didn't solve the problem this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have got solution.

**1.** Create Interface class which works between both Activity : **demoClass.java**

```
public class demoClass {

public static demoClass instance;
public demoInterface mCallback;

public static demoClass getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new demoClass();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void setListener(demoInterface callback) {
    this.mCallback = callback;
}

public void changePage(int which) {
    if(this.mCallback != null) {
        this.mCallback.changePage(which);
    }
}


public interface demoInterface {
    public void changePage(int which);
}
```

}

**2.** From Activity **B** , call interface method :

```
demoClass.getInstance().changePage(mFullscreenViewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

**3.** From Activity **A** , implement interface and register listen to interface :

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity implements demoClass.demoInterface {
...
} 
---------------------
demoClass.getInstance().setListener(ActivityA.this);
```

**4.** Implement `changePage(int)` method in **A** :

```
@Override
public void changePage(int which) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(page);
}
```

**Explaination**

When Activity **B** changes page, report event to interface `demoClass.demoInterface` thorugh `demoClass.getInstance().changePage(index)`. This will ultimately call method `changePage(int)` of Activity **A** and we will change ViewPager content on the go.

**Result**

You can check output at [GIF here](http://giphy.com/gifs/YrUXrnY33RH2M)

Comment: Ok, it's a solution. But if the system releases activity A for some reason, will it work?

Comment: Yes... just you need to save `page` variable value, you can restore when activity A re-starts. For storing, you can use SharedPreference...

Comment: Ok, I will try. Thanks!

Comment: Your solution doesn't solve my issue. The behavior is still this: http://giphy.com/gifs/d3l2J0f2o84YL0tO
Thanks

Comment: Please post your code... because same solution is working for me... i can share code example if you wish...

Comment: From gif, i can say you are resetting mViewPager.setCurrentPage from Activity A somewhere... so page 5 is changing to page 3 when going to Activity A... pls post your code so tht i can help

Comment: I think that trying your code with images instead of text, you'll get the same behavior...

Comment: No... I have used different texts in different pages... It do not have relation with text or image... code is working :)